# Occasional exception passing byte[] to unmanaged function

Tags: c#, memory, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged function with the following signature:

```
WORD GetImage(LPBYTE lpImage);
```

I'm passing a pointer to this method via the `unsafe` and `fixed` keywords as follows:

```
[DllImport(...)]
unsafe static extern Int16 UnmanagedGetImage(void* lpImage);
public static Int16 GetImage(byte[] lpImage)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* ptr = lpImage)
        {
            return UnmanagedGetImage(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

This method is being called as follows:

```
var temp = new byte[this.imageSize.Width * this.imageSize.Height];
var result = GetImage(temp);
```

I then create a `Bitmap` from this information.  This code is working great the majority of the time, but on occasion I've had reports of:

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Is there a fundamental problem with my approach?  I figured that creating a managed byte[] and fixing it to pass to the unmanaged code should be fine, but maybe I should be doing something else.

Comment: `new byte[this.imageSize.Width * this.imageSize.Height]` means it is always one byte per pixel - is it correct assumption for GetImage()?

Comment: The exception probably comes from your unmanaged code function. Debug it. The PInvoke is correct.

Comment: I don't own this DLL or have the code, since it's provided by the hardware vendor.  Their documentation doesn't indicate anything regarding bytes per pixel, though the byte array allocation is taken from one of their samples.  Since it works a large majority of the time, it would be odd if there is only occasionally more than one byte per pixel, but I'm going to contact the vendor to make sure.  Thanks for that idea @Lanorkin

Comment: It also ignores *stride*.  Yes, good odds that the native code corrupts the heap.  Such kind of damage is not guaranteed to make a program fail.